# How can I add a new line in an equation?

Tags: equations, matrices

I used the following block, but it does not add a new line. When I replace `equation` with `gather`, I can add a new line but this time, I get the line `2R_1 + R_2 \xrightarrow{} R_2` with a new equation number (which I do not prefer).

```
\begin{equation}
    2R_1 + R_2 \xrightarrow{} R_2\\
    \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0 & 0\\
        2 & 1 & 0\\
        0 & 0 & 1
    \end{bmatrix}
    \cdot
    \begin{bmatrix}
        a & b & c\\
        d & e & f\\
        g & h & i
    \end{bmatrix}
    =
    \begin{bmatrix}
        a & b & c\\
        d+2a & e+2b & f+2c\\
        g & h & i
    \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `equation` environment does not allow multiline expressions. Use the `aligned` environment from `amsmath` instead.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}


\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
    2R_1 + R_2 &\xrightarrow{} R_2\\
    \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0 & 0\\
        2 & 1 & 0\\
        0 & 0 & 1
    \end{bmatrix}
    \cdot
    \begin{bmatrix}
        a & b & c\\
        d & e & f\\
        g & h & i
    \end{bmatrix}
    &=
    \begin{bmatrix}
        a & b & c\\
        d+2a & e+2b & f+2c\\
        g & h & i
    \end{bmatrix}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}


\end{document}
```

If you want to label the equation, change `equation*` to `equation`, this will only provide you with one label.

In the `aligned` environment, you are able to define *where* your equations should be aligned. I chose to align them at the rightarrow and the equal sign, that's why you see an ampersand in front of those commands.